# How to filter term document matrix based on frequency of occurrence of each term

Tags: r, tm, term-document-matrix

I have a term document matrix. I wish to subset it and keep only those terms which have appeared more than a certain number of times, i.e the row sum should be greater than a specific number. Any quick way to achieve this? B.T.W, the matrix is huge.

Answer (score 1):

yes, so in case you are using the `tm` package there is a findFreqTerms function that you can use where inside the function you can specify the lowfreq you want:

```
tdm # your term document matrix
your_terms <- findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = [...])
```

in case you are interested in reducing the tdm by the most frequent terms you can do:

```
tdm[your_terms, ]
```

hope this helps

Comment: I am actually not looking for the terms. I want to subset the tdm, so that only the terms appearing through findFreqTerms() remain in tdm.

Comment: I've just updated the answer.. is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

In the **quanteda** package:

```
require(quanteda)

myDfm <- dfm(data_char_ukimmig2010, remove_punct = TRUE)
myDfm
## Document-feature matrix of: 9 documents, 1,644 features (81.9% sparse).

# remove infrequent terms
dfm_trim(myDfm, min_count = 10, verbose = TRUE)
## Removing features occurring: 
##   - fewer than 10 times: 1,567
##   Total features removed: 1,567 (95.3%).
## Document-feature matrix of: 9 documents, 77 features (32.5% sparse).
```

Other options exist for removing features based on document frequency, and "sparsity" (a relative measure) as defined in the **tm** package.